# Creating a free form BIRT report using Scripted Datasource

Tags: java, birt

I am trying to create a free form BIRT report. The report is not consisted to rows which have the same columnNames in each row.

Instead, it is a free form report, which will be of the following form.

```
"Name: {FirstName} {LastName}         Addess : {Address}
 Phone#  {Phone#}
....
....
"
```

I am using a scripted datasource, which essentially returns the Map containing the name value pairs of {FirstName, LastName, Address, Phone, and other fields}..

But I am not sure how to set the variables and how do I get the FirstName, LastName etc.
Should I try to use dynamic text.

I don't know of any way in which BIRT can handle non row related data.

Here's my open script of the dataset.

```
open:

    util = new Packages.test.ReportsUtil();
    reportsVO = util.getReportVO("ABC");


in fetch:
    if(currentrow < totalrows) {
        dataSetRow["FirstName"] = reportsVO.getPropValue("identity.FirstName");
        dataSetRow["LastName"] = reportsVO.getPropValue("identity.LastName");    
        currentrow++;
    } else {
        return (false);
    }
```

But I am not sure of how do I get access to the FirstName and LastName in the main layout page.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The goal of a scripted data source is to allow you to leverage the logic inherent in your data model and benefit from any business rules that manipulate that data.  In the end it still wants the data to be formed into a rather traditional row-based set.

You mention dynamic text and I think this would be a great use for the Java-based event handlers.  You can use the logic in the Java object you had bound to the scripted data source to instead tie to an event in the life cycle of the report and get your non-relational data that way.

You can even call your Java object directly from a JavaScript event handler (much easier to plug into via the IDE) using the JS "Packages" construct.

There are many examples to help you get this done at the BIRT Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar (BIRT 3.7) but I used row["colName"] instead of dataSetRow["colName"] and that seems to work.  I have my data in a list, and then each list item is a grid.  I set the data binding in the list to the data set.  The grid is able to see the value as row["colName"].